# Polymer with cordova running slow

Tags: android, performance, cordova, polymer

I am trying to get my app started with android. I have all the HTML pages all ready designed. At first I tried running the polymer with phonegap - the result was very bad, it was very slow. So then I tried running the app with cordova only - I did that using this tutorial: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/ And still the result was not so good, better but still the app was slow.

So now I am wondering what to do? How to solve that problem? I don't know what framework I should use that would make the app run fast.
P.S I don't know if that matters but the app is running on lg g3.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to build your Android app using Intel's Crosswalk project. That enables all devices running Android OS 4.0+ to run with the latest Chromium in the WebViews, which will significantly improve performance. It's a bit of a hassle to include the Crosswalk project manually, but e.g. AppGyver offers it out of the box as a build option. See https://www.appgyver.eu

(Disclaimer: I work for AppGyver.)

Comment: I listened to your advice and tried the appgyver - That is absolutely amazing! Much better hen phonegap. Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to build my project on AppGyver, and there are no error messages. :(